# css not getting applied on IE8, works fine in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, struts2, internet-explorer-8, liferay-6

Overview: Trying to Port a web-app to a struts2 liferay portlet.

Problem Definition: css not getting loaded in IE8.

Description:

I am trying to apply stylesheet.css via my jsp , using the below code snippet

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
    href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/stylesheet.css" media="all" />
```

Below is the code snippet from stylesheet.css written for IE8.

```
#block-system-user-menu ul.lisb li.logout {
    top: -1px;
    right: 0;
    background:url(../images/bg_navTabs.png) repeat-x;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    border-left: solid 1px #345676;
}
#block-system-user-menu ul.lisb li.logout a {
    display: table;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    line-height: 30px;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#block-system-user-menu ul.lisb li.logout a img {
    border:none;
    vertical-align:middle
}
#block-system-user-menu ul.lisb {
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    right: 0;
    display: table;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background:url(../images/bg_topTabs.png) repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border-top: medium none;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}
#block-system-user-menu ul.lisb li {
    list-style: none;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0;
}
#block-system-user-menu ul.lisb li a, #block-system-user-menu ul.lisb li .megapath-phone-support , #block-system-user-menu ul.lisb li span {
    font-size: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #0F345E;
    text-decoration:none;
} 
#block-system-user-menu ul.lisb li a img, #block-system-user-menu ul.lisb li .megapath-phone-support img, #block-system-user-menu ul.lisb li span img {
    border:none;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
#block-system-user-menu ul.lisb li a.support {
    padding-left: 26px;
} 
#block-system-user-menu ul.lisb li span {
    color: #333;
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false)";/* IE8 */
}
#block-system-user-menu ul.lisb li a:hover {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px;
    line-height: 30px;
    background-image: none;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false)";/* IE8 */
    color: #1C9AD6;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#block-system-user-menu ul.lisb li a.support:hover {
    padding-left: 26px;
    background-image: url('./images/icon_supportQ.png'), -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #b8e4f1 0%, #b8e4f1 100%);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false)";/* IE8 */
}


#block-system-user-menu ul.lisb li.first a, #block-system-user-menu ul.lisb li.first .megapath-phone-support, #block-system-user-menu ul.lisb li.first span {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    border-left: medium none;
    color: #0F345E;
    border-right: solid 1px #4589b7;
}
#block-system-user-menu ul.lisb li.first a:hover { 
    color:#fff;
}
#block-system-user-menu ul.lisb li.last a {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    border-left: solid 1px #345676;
}
```

Stylesheet is loaded in Firefox/Chrome but not getting loaded in IE8

Please help!

Comment: why you added `IE8` text at the end of css property? It seems that is making your code not to work.

Comment: @Mr_Green: any other suggestions please? my css doesn't shows up in list of css in IE8 developer option pressed F12.

Comment: Check how the `link` tag is visible in IE8 developer tools and compare it with how it is visible in css loading browsers.

Comment: In exisiting web-app this works fine in IE8:
`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
 href="./css/stylesheet.css" media="all" />`

But in portlet environment, it doesnt work.

`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
 href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/stylesheet.css" media="all" />`

Comment: `link` is similar in other browsers as well, nothing seems to be working here :(

Comment: Can you provide surrounding code too? maybe that is making this problem.

Comment: @Mr_Green:Edited the original post for surrounding code.

Comment: did anybody see any issue here??

Comment: Does it work if you use `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` instead of `<%...%>` ?